# PHP mySQL database check

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I am having endless troubles with duplicate entries, so I need to check the database, and if a user has already entered that day, their entry will not be submitted and they will be redirected to a landing page that tells them they have already entered that day, and that they may only enter again tomorrow.

The field I would like to check is the id_number field in the database, since each user has a unique id number, so basically, if a user with the same id number submitted on the same date they should be redirected to a landing page, how would I go about doing this? I am still new to a lot of this, so please be forgiving.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the mySQL table layout. Besides the "id_number" you'll probably have a date or timestamp field?
Basically, before you insert a row just check if there is already a row with the same id and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you submit your sql query to add a new record you can read the DB first to make sure the ID is not already in there. Get the users id into a variable and do this query.

```
$query = "select * from mytable where `id` = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

then you can count the number of records returned and do different things depending on the result, checking that its zero before adding them.  If its not zero then redirect.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 //add them
}
else
{
 //redirect them
}
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: I think you mean mysql_num_rows($result) == 0

Comment: That looks great, I'll try that quick. How would I check if that specific id number was inserted on the same date? Because they basically need to still be able to submit a form the next day, since each user is only allowed one submission per day... would it maybe look something like this? 

$query = "select * from mytable where `id` = '$id' && where 'date' = '$date'";

Comment: select * from mytable where `id` = '$id' AND `date` = '$date'

Comment: I seem to be getting this error: 

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /usr/wwws/users/ratesg/insurance/funeralplan/funeral-postpage.php on line 9

What could be causing it?